# How to swap Alt-Tab to Ctrl-Tab - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04

I was following a tutorial to swap <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then swap <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> for switching windows. But that tutorial was using compiz but I just red that compiz isn't working any more, something about unity and gnome.

With that said, is there another way to change my window switcher from <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Thanks!

Comment: probably into *System Parameter* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts* -> *Window*

Answer (score 2):

Obviously damadam in the comments pointed to a more straightforward solution. You can change the keyboard combination directly under Settings - Keyboard, section "Navigation".

Below is the more "under the hood" approach which I first posted here. It allows you to have or keep multiple keyboard combinatons for the same action.

Open dconf-edit and change the keybindings for switch-applications from `['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']` to `['<Control>Tab']`. You may need to install dconf-edit first because it is not installed by default.

Alternatively, you may use the terminal to change the setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications ['<Control>Tab']
```

To undo your changes from the terminal and reset to default, issue the command

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications
```